# pass multiple parameter to jtable

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jtable, webmethod, jquery-jtable

this is my jtable initial query.i am not putting the all code here.it's working fine.

```
  $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable({
            title: 'Cheque Details',
            paging: true, //Enables paging
            pageSize: 10, //Actually this is not needed since default value is 10.
            sorting: true, //Enables sorting
            defaultSorting: 'AutoTrNo ASC', //Optional. Default sorting on first load.
            actions: {
                listAction: '/frmAccChequeClear.aspx/TransationList'

            },
```

but my issue is i want to send the parameter in this line

listAction: '/frmAccChequeClear.aspx/TransationList'

my parameter scenario is like this.

DropDown1:  SELECT GLCODE  ->>>>   DropDown2:  SELECT SLCODE

here two dropdown is given.both are cascading dorpdown second is depend on first.

when i select the first dropdown it should take the dropdown dataValuefield

and it should pass the parameter to this

```
 actions: {
        //listAction: '/frmAccChequeClear.aspxTransationList'
        '/frmAccChequeClear.aspx/CheqeList?glcode=' +dropdown.value
        },
```

when i select second one then both dropdown value should pass to these 
parameter

```
 actions: {
    //listAction: '/frmAccChequeClear.aspx/TransationList' 
     '/frmAccChequeClear.aspx/CheqeList?glcode=' + $("dropdown1").val() + "&slcode=" + $("dropdown2").val(),
     },
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
listAction : 'http://localhost:8080/springapp/employee/getEmployeescustom?action=list&param1=123&param2=ganesh&param3=bangalore
```